# Wrong Boolean condition token - Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I don't know how to put a conditioned token to evaluate if a file exists with the Conditional Step Plugin in Jenkins:

[image]

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 54.479 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-09-05T12:57:09+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/56M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception caught evaluating condition: [org.jenkinsci.plugins.tokenmacro.MacroEvaluationException: Unrecognized macro 'test_resultados_miniprueba' in '$test_resultados_miniprueba'], action = [Don't run]
Finished: SUCCESS
```

What is the error in the condition token?

Thanks so much for your time!!!!

Answer (score 0):

In your case `$test_resultados_miniprueba` does not resolve to anything, i.e. it is not a token or environment variable. It seems you wish to test if a file exists? That can be done with the 'File Exists' condition.

The [Conditional Buildstep Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin) uses the [Run Condition Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Run+Condition+Plugin) internally, so you can get a little bit more of documentation there.

Comment: Thanks Joep, I fixed with the "Files Match" Condition. Thanks!